# Show that $\left \{ g\geq a\right \} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and that $\mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$g(x)=x-\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Show that $\left \{  g\geq a\right \} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and that $g \in\mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.
The notation  $\left \{  g\geq a\right \} $ means $ \left \{ x \in  \mathbb{R} : g(x) \geq a \right \}$.

---

If both the range and domain are measurable spaces, then a function is called measurable if the induced $σ$-algebra is a subset of the original $σ$-algebra. We usually show this by showing Borel-measurable when the inverse image $f^{-1}(U)$ is a Borel set for every open set $U$ in the target space.

The sum is throwing me off and the fact that the set is not easily for me to handle.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You mean that you want to show that $\{g \ge a\}=g^{-1}([a,\infty[)$ is a measurable set ?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph of $g$ is an  "inifnite sawtooth wave" and $g$ is clearly bounded by $0$ from below and $1$ from above. Then, the inverse image of a set of the form $[a,\infty)$ is easy to describe:
$$
g^{-1}([a,\infty))=\begin{cases}
\mathbb{R}, & a\le 0, \\
\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}[i+a,i+1), & 0<a< 1, \\
\emptyset, & \ge 1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Ok I see. To show it is measurable w.r.t the set in question; Do I have to show that the elements map to $g$?

Comment: @MantlethebantleCS You need to show that the sets on the RHS are Borel....

Comment: $\mathbb{R}, \emptyset, \bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}[i+a,i+1)$  right? I suppose this can just be mentioned as most of these results are known and the union is unions of real numbers?

Comment: The union is a countable union of half-closed intervals and each such interval is a Borel set.

Comment: I see! So all three sets are borel and thus it follows that $g$ is $\mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$? Why does the last implication follow?

Comment: $g$ is non-negative.

Comment: Of course. To then determine $\lambda(\left \{ g\geq a \right \})$ for all $a\geq 0$ how do I do that?